# Scala Passing variables

Tags: scala, parameter-passing, var

I have in my scala code of socket programming a While loop in which I get the socket.inputstream into a variable

The problem here is that i can not use this variable in the main function or any other function

```
      class NetworkService(port: Int, poolSize: Int) extends Runnable {
  val serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)
  val pool: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize)

  def run() {
    try {
      while (true) {
        // This will block until a connection comes in.
        val socket = serverSocket.accept()
        val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream)).readLine



        pool.execute(new Handler(socket))

      }
    } finally {
      pool.shutdown()


    }
  }

}

class Handler(socket: Socket) extends Runnable {
  def message = (Thread.currentThread.getName() + "\n").getBytes

  def run() {
    socket.getOutputStream.write(message)
    socket.getOutputStream.close()

  }
}


object MyServer {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
(new NetworkService(2030, 2)).run
////////I WANT TO USE THE IN here
}
}
```

I want to pass the variable as a parameter to another function

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does `def run` have to do with this? Why can't to pass the value of the `var` to `println`. Why do you need a `var` there to begin with? Nothing in you example is changing the value of it.

Comment: Run is just another function in the scope and i want to us "in" within the main function

Comment: Are you using single thread?

Comment: i will post the whole code

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: no error 
it's just i want to extract that in variable for later use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `in` in your `main` routine. Logically it doesn't make sense to do so. For one thing there are going to be multiple connections created by the while loop and multiple values for `in`, and so logically there's no single value of `in` that would make sense in the point in `main` after you call `run`. Any code that needs to refer to `in` should be placed inside of the while loop. That might e.g. include a call to another function in which you pass `in` as a parameter.